# VS 2017. Повторный build проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio

После полного build solution, повторный build один проект пересобирает. Из за чего такое может быть?

Comment: вы пытаетесь выяснить, почему один для одного проекта из solution не срабатывает инкрементальный билд? т.е. почему его перебилдовывает, даже если изменений не было? если да - то прямо так и напишите в вопросе, с примером output. а то вопрос хороший, но сформулирован странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в файле проекта была строчка

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

Comment: @0xdb это выглядит как ответ (решение), а не дополнение к вопросу

Comment: @NickVolynkin Согласен, сомневался, т.к. вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: @0xdb вопрос я так понимаю: сначала собрал одной кнопкой все проекты, потом собрал один проект. Почему этот проект собирается с нуля, хотя вроде бы только что собран.

Answer (score 4):

По умолчанию Visual Studio собирает только те проеткты, в которых были изменения во входных файлах. Т.е. если вы нажмете Build два раза подряд, то в первый раз вы получите сообщение вида

```
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Во второй раз вы скорее всего получите сообщение вида:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

В некоторых случаях проект может перебилдовываться даже если во входных файлах не было изменений:

Некоторые типы проектов просто не поддерживают up to date check. Например, SQL Server Database project будет собираться при каждой сборке решения.

Кроме того, студия всегда считает не up-to-date те проекты, в которых есть файлы с Copy to Output Directory' выставленном в 'Copy always'.

Выяснить точную причину, по которой конкретный проект попадает под билд можно выставив Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → MSBuild project build output verbosity в Diagnostics. На этом уровне детализации студия выведет причину билда в окно Output, примерно в таком виде:

```
1>Project 'ConsoleApp37' is not up to date. Project item 'C:\...\TextFile1.txt' 
    has 'Copy to Output Directory' attribute set to 'Copy always'.
```